# Silex (Symfony2 micro framework) redirect in bootstrap.php

Tags: php, session, symfony, redirect, silex

I would like to create a redirect when the user session expires. I know how to do this like so:

```
$app->before(function (Request $request) {
    if (!$request->getSession()->get('displayName')) {
        return new RedirectResponse('login', 301);
    }
});
```

The problem is that I get the error : `Fatal error: Class 'RedirectResponse' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pst/app/bootstrap.php on line 120`

I also tried to add this in the if statement:

```
$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
   return $app->redirect('/hello');
});
```

but the app variable isn't defined. What is the right way to do this?

UPDATE:
I added the RedirectResponse function from Symfony2. But the **displayName** isn't correct. I dumped by session, could anyone take a look of what it should be?
DUMP: http://pastebin.com/7XQbJJ08

In my layout.twig (general layout) I have `<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{  app.user.displayName }}</span>` and after a while no reaction he says he can't find the attribute displayName on a null attribute.

Comment: can you show your full `bootstrap.php` contents?

Comment: Did you forget `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse` at the top of your file?...

Comment: I'm not sure what is meant by displayName isn't correct. It's not in that dump of the session object. Are you sure this has been set in the session?

Comment: I've updated my begin post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first approach you'll need to make sure you've imported the RedirectResponse first. You can do this by adding the following to the top of your script:

```
use \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
```

If this still doesn't work then you may have autoloader problems.

For the second case I'm not sure how $app could be undedfined. As this will have been created when you called:

```
$app = new Silex\Application();
```

Comment: I've added something to my topic, could you take a look?